# Windows store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps

What database can we use to store windows app data dynamically? We are using SQLITE as localDB then when we are wokring with the windows store app dynamically then what database server can we use.?

Answer (score 0):

There are many choices such as Oracle MySQL or MS SQL Server, both of which are commonly used. And you can choose one according to your actual needs.

For  Oracle MySQL :  https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/how-to:-using-mysql-connectornet-with-windows-store-apps

For MS SQL Server :  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c